# Imprimir el texto con los caracteres en posiciones pares en mayúscula

Tags: java

Con este ciclo solo consigo imprimir las letras en la posicion par incluido el cero
Pero no se como hacer para que me imprima el texto con sus letras mayusculas que
estan en la posicion par.

Mas abajo esta el ciclo, el que me pueda ayudar se lo agradeceria mucho

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String texto = "Querido alcohol: Tengo que decirte "
                + "que teni­amos un trato en el cual tu me haci­as ser mas divertido, "
                + "mas guapo, mas inteligente y mejor bailari­n. Ayer vi el vi­deo"
                + ".........Tenemos que hablar.";
        char linea;
        
        String oe;     

        for(int i=0; i<texto.length();i++){
            if(i%2==0){
                linea = texto.charAt(i);
                oe = Character.toString(linea);
                System.out.println(oe.toUpperCase());
            }
        }         
        
    } catch (Exception error) {
        System.out.println("Ocurrió un error: \n" + error);
    } finally {
        System.out.println("Fin de la ejecucion");
    }
}
```

Comment: no termino de entender al 100% tu problema.. ya estas imprimiendo las pares en mayusculas.. o vos queres solo imprimir las que estan en posicion par y que sean mayusculas?

Comment: ah..y si tenes una variable de tipo char.. el nombre linea no le hace honor para nada.. un char es un caracter.. ponele caracter u otra cosa por el estilo... ;)

Comment: Men necesito que en el texto al imprimirlo por consola, me salgan las letras mayuculas que estan en la posicion par, hasta el momento solo consigo imprimir las letras que estan en la posicion par, no se como hacer que esas letras en posicion par aparezcan en mayuscula en todo el texto, has de cuenta que por cada dos letras del texto estas salen en mayuscula

Comment: Podes poner lo que sale, y lo que queres que salga?

Comment: dale bro aparece de la siguiente manera:

Comment: QEIOACHL EG U EITQETN­MSU RT NE ULT EHC­SSRMSDVRIO A UP,MSITLGNEYMJRBIAIN YRV LV­E.....EEO U ALR

Comment: y quiero que salga asi: "QuErIdO AlCoHoL: TEnGo que dEcIrTe "
                    + "QuE TeNiaMoS Un Trato en el cual tu me hacias ser mas divertido, "
                    + "mas guapo, mas inteligente y mejor bailarin. Ayer vi el video"
                    + ".........Tenemos que hablar.";

Comment: Osea por cada 2 letras esa letra aparece en mayuscula, pero solo me imprime esas letras mas no las letras mas el texto

Comment: eso que sale.. no es lo que escribiste en tu post.. y por favor, cuando te piden aclaraciones, usa el boton [edit] y agrega la informacion en la pregunta... si le pones comentarios a tu codigo, te vas a dar cuenta de tu error.. basicamente tenes que transformar a mayusculas solo los pares... o sea.. tenes que imprimir todo.. pero tu if esta mal ubicado... tu codigo esta todo y es correcto, solo tenes que ordenarlo....

Comment: Esta bien lo tendre en cuenta, pero dime por fa como puedo arreglar el codigo si lo tengo bueno, osea donde pongo el if y el ciclo? Osea con lo que tengo como puedo resolver el problema

Comment: pone comentarios en tu codigo.. y sale solo.. si vos queres todos los caracteres, que linea te devuelve el caracter actual? si vos qures mayusculas solo los pares, que linea se fija si es par y que linea pone en mayusculas? y que linea imprime.. son 4 lineas.. solo es una cuestion de orden.....

Comment: Dale gracias!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agregando un else al primer if, si es par lo imprimis como Mayuscula, sino minuscula. Cambien el println por print para que imprima en la misma linea.
Tambien como dijeron en un comentario el nombre lina para un caracter no es buena practica asi que lo cambie a c.

```
public class NewClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     try {
        String texto = "Querido alcohol: Tengo que decirte "
                + "que teni­amos un trato en el cual tu me haci­as ser mas divertido, "
                + "mas guapo, mas inteligente y mejor bailari­n. Ayer vi el vi­deo"
                + ".........Tenemos que hablar.";
        char c;
        
        for(int i=0; i<texto.length();i++){
                c = texto.charAt(i);
            if(i%2==0){;
                c = Character.toUpperCase(c);
                System.out.print(c);
            }else{
                System.out.print(c);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception error) {
        System.out.println("Ocurrió un error: \n" + error);
    } finally {
        System.out.println("Fin de la ejecucion");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué hace este código? Lee [answer] y pulsa en [edit] para agregar más detalles a tu respuesta.

Answer (score 3):

```
String texto = "Querido alcohol: Tengo que decirte "
             + "que teni­amos un trato en el cual tu me haci­as ser mas divertido, "
             + "mas guapo, mas inteligente y mejor bailari­n. Ayer vi el vi­deo"
             + ".........Tenemos que hablar.";

String nuevoTexto = "";

for(int i = 0; i < texto.length(); i++)
{
   if(i % 2 == 0 && Character.isLetter(texto.charAt(i)))
   {
      nuevoTexto += Character.toUpperCase(texto.charAt(i));
   }
   else
   {
      nuevoTexto += texto.charAt(i);
   }
}

System.out.println(nuevoTexto);
```

Lo que se hace aquí es un **ciclo for** que itera desde la primera posición de tu cadena hasta la última, y por cada posición pregunta si ese caracter se encuentra en una posición par dentro de la cadena y si es una letra(ya que caracteres como **'.'**) no se llevan a mayúscula.

De cumplirse esta condición se convierte esa letra a mayúscula y se concatena al texto de la **variable nuevoTexto**. De no cumplirse esta condición se concatena ese caracter a la **variable nuevoTexto** tal como aparece en la cadena original.

Para preguntar si un caracter es una letra se usa la **función isLetter** y para convertir un caracter a mayúscula se usa la **función toUpperCase**.

Comment: Que buen aporte, no recordaba la funcion isletter, gracias por tu ayuda compañero